# Boolean Not in OpenCV 3.1

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to know if there's a simple way of doing a boolean "not" operation on a cv::Mat. This does not work:

```
cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat::ones(3,3, CV_8U);
cv::Mat mat_not = !mat;
```

As such, is there an effective or simple way to do this? Should I resort to using something like this:

```
cv::Mat mat_not = mat < cv::Mat::ones(3,3,CV_8U);
```

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I confused the "not" operator between MATLAB and C++ (since I'm translating the first one to the other). This works fine:

```
cv::Mat map2 = ~map1;
```

Comment: boolean not is `~`

Comment: Oh! Yeah that's obvious! Thanks for pointing this out. Been translating Matlab code to C++, it got me confused!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: 12:30pm 7/20/2016

I see the op wants a regular NOT and I'm used to that being different for things like IDL and MatLab etc..

As @cxyzs7, @Cedric, and @Miki mentioned the operator in c++ is ~  so ...

```
mat = ~mat;
```

However if you ever want to do something else element wise (for example a bitwise) most of the time there's already a whole function for that. IE...

[bitwise_not](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=bitwise_not#cv2.bitwise_not)

```
cv::Mat src;
src = stuff;
cv::Mat dst;

//then call it
bitwise_not(src,dst);
```

If the function you want to do element by element is non-existent in the library or isn't an overloaded operator you can always do it the brute force way...

```
for(...) {
     for (...) {
        dst.at<int>(i,j) = ! src.at<int>(i,j);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! :) BTW, is it safe to use the same src matrix as the dst matrix, such as `bitwise_not(mat1, mat1);` ? Thanks!

Comment: But `bitwise_not` is not `not`. I thought the OP want mat_not = cv::Mat::zeros() after the `not` operator. But `bitwise_not` would give a 3 by 3 matrix with element all equal to 254, right? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I guess you could interpret what he asked as that. I'm not sure. But I know for certain !mat is wrong. You could also do each element at a time with mat.at<some_type>( i , j ) = ! mat.at<some_type>( i , j ); in a for loop.

Comment: As pointed out by @Miki, boolean not is ~ in C++. I've been confusing C++ and MATLAB. `mat2 = ~map1` is fine. Moreover, bitwise_not is not exactly a `not` operator, but in the case of boolean matrix in OpenCV, it acts the same, since bool Mat are uint8_t and `false` has a value of 0 (0b00000000) and `true` has a value of 255 (0b11111111), making bitwise_not acting exactly the same as simple `not`.